# How to set content description of a switch or toggle button in Android Studio?

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I would like to make my app accessible with Tlkback, but I don't know how could I set different content descriptions for both states of a switch or toggle button.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can set content description programmatically like this.

```
toggleButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick( View v ) {
            if( toggleButton.isChecked() ) {
                toggleButton.setContentDescription( "Selected" );
            } else {
                toggleButton.setContentDescription( "Unselected" );
            }
        }
    } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `AccessibilityNodeInfo`'s `setChecked` and `setCheckable`. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo#setCheckable(boolean)

```
class MyAccessibilityDelegate extends View.AccessibilityDelegate {

  MyButton button;

  public constructor (MyButton button) {
    this.button = button;
  }

  @Override
  public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View host, AccessibilityNodeInfo info) {
    super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info);
    
    info.setCheckable(true);
    info.setChecked(button.getChecked());
```

And then add delegate to your view/layout/etc.

```
class MyButton extends View {
...
  public constructor() {
    setAccessibilityDelegate(new MyAccessibilityDelegate(this);
  }
...
}
```

Explanation: All accessibility services should be using `AccessibilityNodeInfo` to determine what is spoken out loud. `setCheckable` makes the service aware that the `View` has modifiable states, while `setChecked` actually changes the "checked/not checked" callout.

Comment: If there is a view/row that has a couple of textviews AND a switch, we need to add `MyAccessibilityDelegate` to the root of the view so the TalkBack read all together. Then, the new issue will be, TalkBack will read the state of the Switch sooner.

Comment: If you want accessibility focus to stop at the root, then you can set `importantForAccessibility=true` for the root View's xml. TalkBack will automatically aggregate all the children view's accessibility info and read them in accessibility order, including the child `MyButton` with `MyAccessibilityDelegate`.

Comment: My issue is the root has `importantForAccessibility="yes"` but, TalkBack reads all children except the Switch! That's the reason I came to this question and answer. To set the cd with the delegate; which didn't work either.(I tried both solutions, set the delegate on Switch and Parent)

Comment: Oh interesting. What class is your root view? Have you tried checking the [node info tree](https://withintent.uncorkedstudios.com/tutorial-debugging-android-accessibility-818cfd361414#:~:text=Turn%20on%20Node%20Tree%20Debugging&text=In%20Settings%20%3E%20Accessibility%20%3E%20TalkBack%20%3E,output%20level%20to%20%E2%80%9CVerbose.%E2%80%9D)? Without knowing more, my guess is that either the Switch isn't being set as an Accessibility child

Comment: The root is `CardView`. then next parent is `ConstraintLayout`.